# WPF Scaling DPI issue

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Application crops in screens having scaling percentage **125%**. It works for the screen having scaling percentage as **100%**.

I tried with these solution.

> 1) Right click on the application you want to correct the fonts of,
>   select Properties
>
> 2) Go to Compatibility tab.
>
> 3) Under Settings section, check Disable display scaling on high DPI
>   settings
>
> 4) Apply and close the window.

This doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Robert - you must be more specific with your questions on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. WPF apps scale well with DPI change, you must provide an example to proof something doesn't scale.